# android - detect changes on web folder

Tags: android, detection

I'm developing an app which reads content loaded on my company's server. How can I detect if new files are loaded into the designated folder online or whether any of the existing files has been overwritten in that folder?

From what I've researched so far,
(1) FileObserver seems to be a likely solution, but can it check on a specific URL?
(2) I've used Json's Request.Method.HEAD on a single file to detect updates, but I currently have close to 500 over files (and growing) in that folder and it seems like a potential resource hog to process the header information every time the app loads.

Anyone has suggestion on what functions to use, or library which can help in this scenario?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I detect if new files are loaded into the designated folder online or whether any of the existing files has been overwritten in that folder?

Have the server notify your app of changes, such as via GCM.

Or, have the server publish some sort of a changelog that you monitor.

> FileObserver seems to be a likely solution, but can it check on a specific URL?

`FileObserver` is for local files.

> I've used Json's Request.Method.HEAD on a single file to detect updates, but I currently have close to 500 over files (and growing) in that folder and it seems like a potential resource hog to process the header information every time the app loads.

Agreed. Your problem is on the server. Your server needs to provide the change details in a more efficient fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Create a small API that will have method smth like

`List<String url> getAllChangedFiles(long timestamp)` that return all files that had been changed from your date. In this case all time consuming logic (like searching for such files) will be on the server, you even could cache it for some reasons.

GCM is not a perfect solution 'cause there is no guarantee that your push notification will be delivered.